# How to limit the amount of times a javascript highlight function can be used?

Tags: javascript, limit, counter, highlight

I have this JavaScript function that highlight table TD's when clicked on each individual TD

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function(){
    var all = document.getElementsByClassName("clicker");
    for (var i=0;i<all.length;i++) {
        all[i].onclick = inputClickHandler;       
    }
};

function inputClickHandler(e){
    e = e||window.event;
    var tdElm = e.target||e.srcElement;
    if(tdElm.style.backgroundColor == 'rgb(0, 153, 0)'){
        tdElm.style.backgroundColor = '#fff';
    } else {
        tdElm.style.backgroundColor = '#009900';
    }
}
    </script>
```

And I have a table say 8 by 8 and they are all square.  Now above the table I have a form with a selection menu which looks like this.

```
<form id="filter">
<select id="highlights" name="highlights">
<option value="0"> Select... </option>
<option value="20"> 20 </option>
<option value="24"> 24 </option>
<option value="28"> 28 </option>
<option value="30"> 30 </option>
</select>
```

Basically what I want is for the user to select an option from the highlights form, so say I pick "24", it then only allows me to highlight "24" squares in the table.  If I change from "24" to "28" im then allowed to highlight "28" and no more than what is selected.
How would I do this?

Comment: While highlighting a cell, compare `#highlights`'s selected value with the current number of highlighted cells?!

Comment: Ye I tried doing that, I did an If statement and had a counter, and when I clicked a TD to highlight it, I told it that the counter was equal to counter plus 1, and when I removed a highlight I told it the counter was equal to counter minus 1, and then did an If statement to say if the counter was less than the selected value that it could run the function and if not then it couldnt, but it didnt work

Comment: That's one way of doing it, but why reimplement the counter? With the highlighted cells you allready have a counter. So just count the currently highlighted cells, and base your decision on that.

Comment: Just so you know, Im not very strong with JavaScript at all

Comment: Okay, no problem ;)  Final question: Did you not use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) on purpose? It would make things a lot easier.

Comment: I have no idea on how to use jQuery, I wouldnt even know where to begin with it LOL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do something like this:

```
var max = 0, highlighted = 0
document.getElementById('highlights').onchange = function () {
  max = this.value
}
...
function inputClickHandler(e){
  e = e||window.event;
  var tdElm = e.target||e.srcElement;
  if(tdElm.style.backgroundColor == 'rgb(0, 153, 0)'){
    highlighted--
    tdElm.style.backgroundColor = '#fff';
  } else if (highlighted != max) {
    highlighted++
    tdElm.style.backgroundColor = '#009900';
  }
}
```

Comment: No it doesnt seem to work in that, I literally copied and pasted every bit of code I had and it displayed right, but it wasnt working

Comment: OK, hold on while I set up a demo.

Comment: Thanks, this does work, so thats a lot for helping, but there is just one more thing, not sure if you can help, if not then it really doesnt matter.  But say I click 20 to only select 20, and I select 20 squares, it does limit me, then I change to 24, and it allows me to select 4 more squares.  However if I change back to 20, it allows me to select as many as id like again.  Is there a way around this, if not it really doesnt matter.

Comment: Yes, we can change that. What SHOULD happen in this case?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply,  Well I guess it could just not let you add anymore until you remove the extra highlighted td's, so if we selected 20 when 24 were previously selected then you would have to remove 4+ to do anything.

Comment: Or maybe If you had 24 selected and you changed the selection to 20 you could get a pop up message box saying please remove 4 highlights before selecting a different filter

Comment: Something like that if possible

Comment: OK, here you go: http://jsbin.com/italuf/3/edit. When the limit is lowered, you must unselect squares before you can continue. Let me know if this helps :)